# how use google play services license on new Huawei devices like Huawei nova 7i

Tags: android, google-play-services, huawei-mobile-services

There is not GMS on new Huawei devices, and because of the license of google and Huawei sanction, Analytics, Crashlytics, and FCM are not working on these devices.
How could have these libs work on Huawei devices?

- add both GMS, HMS, and code branching?
- ignoring these devices!?
- use or implement independence libs of GMS and HMS?

Which one could be a good way to consider maintenance in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Although your question is very opinion based, both GMS / HMS code branching or implementing independence libraries are clearly the best options. At first glance it may seem as more maintenance, but it gives you a window to not be stuck in single market, and with the right abstraction layer you may end up with a nice implementation which requires not so much maintenance and can be expanded to other future markets.

I wouldn't go with the option to ignore devices, as the sanctions will eventually disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Even I have faced the same issue. Now i am going with the option of **3. use or implement independence libs of GMS and HMS**

I am using the following plugin **CordovaHMSGMSCheckPlugin** to check whether the device supports GMS or HMS, based on the result i have changed my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You are advised to use the solution for integrating both GMS and HMS. The advantages are as follows:

1. Reduce the complexity of app packaging. A package can be released to both Google Play and HUAWEI AppGallery.
2. Reduce the code maintenance cost. The HMS+GMS adaptation layer code is added to the original logic code. In this way, proper code can be automatically called based on the mobile phone. That is, you do not need to modify existing logic code or maintain two sets of code.

You are advised to use [HUAWEI HMS ToolKit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/.), which can help you quickly add the HMS+GMS adaptation layer code and upgrade your logic code to support both GMS and HMS.